# AVG duplication SQL

Tags: sql

I'm currently having issues creating two columns with AVG for different date ranges.

I've tried the below code to try and resolve this.

```
WITH Tbl AS(
    SELECT FORMAT(SaleDate,'MM')+'.'+FORMAT(SaleDate,'yyyy') AS SALE_MY, Employee, NewScheme
FROM Salereport
WHERE Business Area='Sales'
)

SELECT
AgentName, 
(SELECT AVG(NewScheme) FROM Tbl WHERE SALE_MY='01.2019' OR SALE_MY='02.2019' OR SALE_MY='03.2019'),
(SELECT AVG(NewScheme) FROM Tbl WHERE SALE_MY='04.2019' OR SALE_MY='05.2019' OR SALE_MY='06.2019')


FROM Tbl

GROUP BY Employee
```

Result is just the same AVG for everyone.

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Employee,
       AVG(CASE WHEN SaleDate >= '2019-01-01' AND SaleDate < '2019-04-01'
                THEN NewScheme
           END),
       AVG(CASE WHEN SaleDate >= '2019-01-04' AND SaleDate < '2019-04-07'
                THEN NewScheme
           END),
FROM Salereport
WHERE Business Area = 'Sales'
GROUP BY Employee;
```

When working with dates, you should be using date operations.  The only time you normally need to convert to a string is to format dates in the result set.

Incidentally, your version is taking the average across *all* employees.  No subquery is needed, but if you were to use one, you would want a correlated subquery.

Comment: That worked, thank you. I got lost in my own train of thought - This will help me a lot going forward.

Comment: How would we introduce not including NULL into this case when?

Comment: @Wyseguy . . . I don't understand your comment.  `NULL` values don't affect the average.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 WITH Tbl AS(
        SELECT FORMAT(SaleDate,'MM')+'.'+FORMAT(SaleDate,'yyyy') AS SALE_MY, Employee, NewScheme
    FROM Salereport
    WHERE Business Area='Sales'
    )
    SELECT Employee, 
    AVG(CASE WHEN SALE_MY IN ('01.2019', '02.2019', '03.2019') THEN NewScheme ELSE NULL END) AS Q1_Avg, 
    AVG(CASE WHEN SALE_MY IN ('04.2019', '05.2019', '06.2019') THEN NewScheme ELSE NULL END) AS Q2_Avg
    FROM Tbl
    GROUP BY Employee
```

Comment: @Gordon is right, you don't need to convert the date to string. His answer will have much  better performance